# DB2: Как вывести в нормализованной таблице данные из других таблиц?

Tags: база-данных, db2, ibm, sql

СУБД DB2 v10.1 на WINDOWS 7. У меня есть три таблицы:

1. table Rase

   ```
   id  Rases   Length
   1   Москва  300
   2   Питер   400
   ```
2. table Plan

   ```
   id  Name    Date
   1   ТУ124   10.12.1987
   2   Ан24    10.01.1998
   ```
3. table Kril

   ```
    ID      COLOR                    WEIGH    
     1      Зеленый                  124,56
     2      Серый                    187,40
     3      Коричневый               231,00
   ```

Необходимо вывести данные в нормализованной таблице ALL_D, представленном ниже виде:

> - ID – первичный ключ
> - Plan – ссылка на Plan.Name
> - Kril – ссылка на Kril.Color
> - Race – ссылка на Race.Rases
> - Time_Start – время отправления (CURRENT TIMESTAMP)

table ALL_D

```
ID  Name    Color   Rases   Time_Start
1   ТУ124   Зеленый Москва  2011-10-25-19.12.30.000000
2   АН24    Красный Питер   2011-10-27-17.14.30.000000
```

Не хочет здесь нормально отображаться последняя таблица.

[image]

Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: решил попробовать сделать через insert into ... from select ... join... join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into all_d
    select rase.id, plan.name, kril.color, rase.rases, 
           current timestamp as time_start
        from rase
        join plan on plan.id = rase.id
        join kril on kril.id = rase.id
```

Задача решена:) спасибо за внимание.